# .htaccess - Redirect all pages to https version of site and other domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I currently have the following code within my `.htaccess` file. this ensures that my two other domains are redirected to my main URL. It also ensures that my current domain is redirected to self but with `www` should it have not been present.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co\.uk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co\.uk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newexample\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newexample.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

My question is, how can i ensure that they all use `https` if it isn't already present. The above code seems to work unless someone types in `www.newexample.com` then it is not redirected to `https`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co\.uk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newexample\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newexample.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co\.uk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newexample\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newexample.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, it says that it can not open the page because too many redirects occurred? If i remove this line `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]` it works without the redirect loop error, but then it doesn't implement the rule of `https`

Comment: Is there some rule/framework that is redirecting it back to `http://` or `non-www` in your system? Can you open your page in FIrebug and see what you get in Net tab?

Comment: I checked it in firebug net tab and get a repeating error `301 Moved Permanently`

Comment: That means you have some code/framework redirecting back to `http://`.  Do you have any CMS/PHP framework running?

Comment: I'm not using a frame work of any kind. I upgraded my domain hosting to `https://` in which the hosting company i use had to change some DNS setting to a virtual server. Would this be an issue?

Comment: It could be the issue. Even when first condition commented in above rule what happens when you enter `http://www.newexample.com/`?

Comment: OR else do you have any other rule OR any other .htaccess in your system?

Comment: With the first one commented out it just behaves as it did before. It doesn't loop or redirect to `https://`. I do not have any other rules within the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: No with the firs condition commented what happens when you enter `https://www.newexample.com/` (URL with `https//`) does it stay as https?

Comment: The updated version has the redirect loop error also. With you original code, the first line commented out the following url works fine `https://www.newexample.com/`.

Comment: Can you try this out in a new browser? There is something in your code probably that is enforcing `http://`